# Before engineered wood over unlevel concrete slab floor

Tags: adhesive, engineered-flooring

Steps needed, or if recommended, before laying engineered hardwood over unlevel slab floor. Self leveling mix?  Moisture barrier or just rubberized adhesive? Anything else?

Comment: Is the slab just unlevel/has a slope, or does it have dips/ridges/waves?  Those floors want a flat/straight surface.  They do not care about slopes if they are flat.  Dips/ridges need to be flatten out.

Comment: Please provide info about the type of construction and specifics about the area you are putting the wood. Also where on the planet you are.  Most slab homes have vapor barrier under the slab.  It must be there by code before the concrete is poured.  However if you are putting flooring down on what was previously a porch or garage, there can be no vapor barrier.  So the whats and where of your project are important to get the best advice.